# Creating one to one relationship SQL

Tags: sql, m

What is the best way to create one to one relationship from these two tables
?

```
CREATE TABLE hotel(
id_Hotel
...

)

CREATE TABLE Manager(
ID_Manager
...

)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably, each hotel has a manager, so a place to start is with a manager id in the hotel table.

Comment: Why does this need to be a 1-1 relationship? Are you not keeping the history of managers once they leave? Look into Foreign Keys and Unique Constraints for the joins.

Comment: Its a school asignment to use one 1 to 1 relationship, but I might just leave it. Since its a school project, I do not have to keep the history of managers. So I will probably do this  create table Hotel(id_Hotel INT, id_Manager INT...)   and create table Manager(Id_Manager, ....)

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be:

```
create table Hotel(id_Hotel INT, id_Manager INT...)
```

But a more practical solution is:

```
create table Hotel(id_Hotel INT, ...);
create table Manager(id_Manager INT, ...);
create table Hotel_Manager(id_HM INT, id_Hotel INT, id_Manager INT, CreateDate Date);
```

Comment: The `id_HM` is useless. Just make `(id_Hotel, id_Manager)`  the primary key in `Hotel_Manager`. But that isn't a one-to-one relationship, that's many-to-many

Comment: I love it when you fix my stuff, @a_horse_with_no_name